# Print out current properties of your ThemeData

Tags: flutter, dart

Is it possible to print out the value of your theme data?

I would love to do print(ThemeData);

and have every single property listed.

I need to find out who is the culprit tinging my dialog box purple as you can see below.

FYI: I already customized the dialog theme data so i doubt it is that:

```
        dialogTheme: const DialogTheme(
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
            surfaceTintColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
```

This is coming from the package called: datetime_picker_formfield_new
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So i figured it out, you need to set the new material 3 property surfacetint to transparent and then to make the datepicker form stand out change the header and background color like so:

```
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
        primary: primaryColor,
        secondary: secondaryColor,
        background: backgroundColor,
        error: errorColor,
        surfaceTint: Colors.transparent,
    );
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
            headerBackgroundColor: primaryColor,
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
        ),
```

Here is my complete themedata if anyone is interested:

```
//flutter packages
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:zandu_mobile_admin/constants/main.dart';

//issues
//ignore_for_file: constant_identifier_names

//notes
// https://resocoder.com/2019/08/09/switch-themes-with-flutter-bloc-dynamic-theming-tutorial-dark-light-theme/
//fonts that are loaded that we can use are: Jost, Muli, Oswald, WorkSans, Comfortaa, Baloo2, RalewayDotsRegular, Spartan, DancingScript, Poppins, GoogleSans
//WorkSans i like a lot, Muli is good but looks very similar to WorksSans, Comfortaa is pretty good, GoogleSans sucks, Poppins is ok, Oswald sucks, DancingScript is handwritting and is mostly used to test the themes

//set the main font name here instead of in 3 places
const String mainFont = 'Poppins';

enum AppTheme {
    DefaultLight,
    DefaultDark,
}

final appThemeData = {
    AppTheme.DefaultLight: _buildLightTheme(),
    AppTheme.DefaultDark: _buildDarkTheme(),
};

ThemeData _buildLightTheme() {
    const Color primaryColor = Color(colors_zanduadminprimary);
    const Color secondaryColor = Color(colors_zanduadminaccent);
    const Color errorColor = Color(0xFFB00020);
    const Color canvasColor = Colors.white;
    const Color dividerColor = Color(0xFF999999);
    const Color scaffoldBackgroundColor = Colors.white;
    const Color splashColor = Colors.white24;
    const Color backgroundColor = Colors.white;
    const Color indicatorColor = Colors.white;
    //const Color testingColor = Colors.purple;
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = const ColorScheme.light().copyWith(
        primary: primaryColor,
        secondary: secondaryColor,
        background: backgroundColor,
        error: errorColor,
        surfaceTint: Colors.transparent,
    );
    
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: primaryColor,
        primaryColorLight: primaryColor,
        primaryColorDark: primaryColor,
        canvasColor: canvasColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        dividerColor: dividerColor,
        splashColor: splashColor,
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            colorScheme: colorScheme,
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
        dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
            color: dividerColor,
        ),
        indicatorColor: indicatorColor,
        fontFamily: mainFont,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
            displayLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            displayMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            displaySmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            headlineLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            headlineMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            headlineSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            titleLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            titleMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            titleSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            bodyLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black), //default text when no style is defined
            bodyMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            bodySmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.black),
            labelLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
            labelMedium: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
            labelSmall: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            color: primaryColor,//same as backgroundColor
            //backgroundColor: Colors.xxx,
            //foregroundColor: Colors.xxx,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
            )
        ),
        tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            dividerColor: primaryColor,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        listTileTheme: ListTileThemeData(
            iconColor: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
            //the color inside the switch //FLUTTER-SENSEI-0025
            trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? primaryColor : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2)),
            //the border around the switch //FLUTTER-SENSEI-0025
            trackOutlineColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? Colors.transparent : Colors.transparent),
            //we were never able to match the grey of the track color using Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2). Something is happening to the colors when it is applied.
            //trackOutlineColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? primaryColor : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.2)),
            thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),//the round selector we slide
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),//when you grab it to slide it
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5)),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.5))
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2, color: primaryColor)
            ),
            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1.0)
            ),
        ),
        drawerTheme: const DrawerThemeData(
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
        ),
        dialogTheme: const DialogTheme(
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
            headerBackgroundColor: primaryColor,
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
        ),
        colorScheme: colorScheme,
    );
    
    return base.copyWith(
        textTheme: _buildTextTheme(base.textTheme),
        primaryTextTheme: _buildTextTheme(base.primaryTextTheme),
    );
    
}

ThemeData _buildDarkTheme() {
    const Color primaryColor = Color(colors_zanduadminprimary);
    const Color secondaryColor = Color(colors_zanduadminaccent);
    const Color errorColor = Color(0xFFB00020);
    const Color canvasColor = Color(0xFF202124);
    const Color dividerColor = Color(0xFF999999);
    const Color scaffoldBackgroundColor = Color(0xFF202124);
    const Color splashColor = Colors.white24;
    const Color backgroundColor = Color(0xFF202124);
    const Color indicatorColor = Colors.white;
    //const Color testingColor = Colors.purple;
    final ColorScheme colorScheme = const ColorScheme.dark().copyWith(
        primary: primaryColor,
        secondary: secondaryColor,
        background: backgroundColor,
        error: errorColor,
        surfaceTint: Colors.transparent,
    );
    
    final ThemeData base = ThemeData(
        useMaterial3: true,
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primaryColor: primaryColor,
        primaryColorLight: primaryColor,
        primaryColorDark: primaryColor,
        canvasColor: canvasColor,
        scaffoldBackgroundColor: scaffoldBackgroundColor,
        dividerColor: dividerColor,
        splashColor: splashColor,
        splashFactory: InkRipple.splashFactory,
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.orange,
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            colorScheme: colorScheme,
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
        ),
        dividerTheme: const DividerThemeData(
            color: dividerColor,
        ),
        indicatorColor: indicatorColor,
        //hintColor: Colors.xxx,
        fontFamily: mainFont,
        textTheme: const TextTheme(
            displayLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 26.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            displayMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            displaySmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 22.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            headlineLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            headlineMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 18.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            headlineSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            titleLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, color: Colors.white),
            titleMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            titleSmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            bodyLarge: TextStyle(fontSize: 16.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white), //default text when no style is defined
            bodyMedium: TextStyle(fontSize: 14.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            bodySmall: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500, color: Colors.white),
            labelLarge: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
            labelMedium: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
            labelSmall: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),//not used anywhere and the font size was never set
        ),
        appBarTheme: const AppBarTheme(
            color: primaryColor,//same as backgroundColor
            //backgroundColor: Colors.xxx,
            //foregroundColor: Colors.xxx,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(
                color: Colors.white,
            )
        ),
        tabBarTheme: TabBarTheme(
            indicatorColor: Colors.white,
            dividerColor: primaryColor,
            labelColor: Colors.white,
            unselectedLabelColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        listTileTheme: ListTileThemeData(
            iconColor: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5),
        ),
        switchTheme: SwitchThemeData(
            //the color inside the switch //FLUTTER-SENSEI-0025
            trackColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? primaryColor : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
            //the border around the switch //FLUTTER-SENSEI-0025
            trackOutlineColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? Colors.transparent : Colors.transparent),
            //we were never able to match the grey of the track color using Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2). Something is happening to the colors when it is applied.
            //trackOutlineColor: MaterialStateProperty.resolveWith((states) => states.contains(MaterialState.selected) ? primaryColor : Colors.white.withOpacity(0.2)),
            thumbColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.white),//the round selector we slide
            overlayColor: MaterialStateProperty.all(Colors.transparent),//when you grab it to slide it
        ),
        inputDecorationTheme: InputDecorationTheme(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5)),
            ),
            enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: BorderSide(width: 1.0, color: Colors.white.withOpacity(0.5))
            ),
            focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 2, color: primaryColor)
            ),
            disabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1.0)
            ),
        ),
        drawerTheme: const DrawerThemeData(
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
        ),
        dialogTheme: const DialogTheme(
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
            shadowColor: Colors.black,
        ),
        datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
            headerBackgroundColor: primaryColor,
            backgroundColor: canvasColor,
        ),
        colorScheme: colorScheme,
    );
    
    return base.copyWith(
        textTheme: _buildTextTheme(base.textTheme),
        primaryTextTheme: _buildTextTheme(base.primaryTextTheme),
    );
    
}

TextTheme _buildTextTheme(TextTheme base) {
    
    return base.copyWith(
        bodyMedium: base.bodyMedium!.copyWith(
            fontFamily: mainFont,
        ),
    );
    
}
```